# My toilet won't flush, and just adds water

Tags: bathroom, toilet

my toilet won't flush. All it does is fill up with water and sit there. It's not even draining the water. I have let it sit all night and still is the same water level in the morning. I've been plunging it and nothing happens. What can I do?

Comment: sounds like the sewer pipe is totally plugged up ... you can call a plumber

Comment: The kind of plunger you use is important. Also the correct way to use a plunger is to gently push down and get a good seal, and then pull back hard so the suction pulls the clog back up *not pushes it down farther in jamming it in tighter*.

Comment: maybe drop in some dulcolax ?

Comment: @Alaska Man your instructions on how to use a plunger should be an answer.

Comment: Is this toilet the only drain stopped up? If so, the blockage *may be* in the toilet itself and not in the sewer from the toilet. If so, proper plunging can unblock it.

Answer (score 2):

Had a similar problem last year. Called a plumber and he found that the drainpipe was clogged by roots close to the street which prevented the water from escaping. If your toilet has an inspection outlet you could check to see if this is also full to find out where the blockage is. Next step would be to call your Water supplier to find out if the blockage is on their land (street-side). If they tell you the blockage is on your property, then you would call a plumber as they have the equipment to find and clear the blockage.